# How to "upgrade" hourglass pattern generator?

Tags: python, hourglass

I'm making an exercise with patterns in Python and I've did a hourglass pattern for n=5 but when I'm trying with other odd number e.g. `n`==7, it's destroyed. Any suggestions how to upgrade my code?

```
def hourglass(num_of_rows):
    #upper piece
    for i in range(num_of_rows-(num_of_rows//2)):
        print(' '*i+ character*(num_of_rows-2*i))
    #lower piece without the middle one
    for j in range(num_of_rows-1-(num_of_rows//2), -1, -2):
        print(' '*(j-1) +character*(num_of_rows-j))

num_of_rows=5
character = 'x'
hourglass(num_of_rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact upgrade to what you have done, you can use recursion to get what you want. This however will not work if `n` is an even number, I dont know how the hour glass will be for an even number, I can change it accordingly if you specify. `str.center` can be used to do the padding without doing any of those math. Let me know if any explanation is needed.

```
def hour_glass(n, character, width=None):
    if width is None:
        width = n
    if n == 1:
        print(character.center(width))
        return
    to_print = (character * n).center(width)
    print(to_print)
    hour_glass(n - 2, character, width)
    print(to_print)
```

Output

```
hour_glass(7, 'X')

XXXXXXX
 XXXXX 
  XXX  
   X   
  XXX  
 XXXXX 
XXXXXXX

hour_glass(5, 'X')

XXXXX
 XXX 
  X  
 XXX 
XXXXX
```

Comment: I've never tried a recursion but it's impressive thanks a lot